# Hit url for 50000 parellel request

Tags: go

I am trying to hit any sample url for parallel 50000 requests. But I get various kinds of error. Can somebody let me know what am I doing wrong? Or what should be the strategy?

```
func MakeRequests(url string, ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(10)) * time.Millisecond)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    ch <- resp.StatusCode
    wg.Done()
}

func main() {

    var waitGroup sync.WaitGroup 
    count := 0
    ch := make(chan int)
    url := "http://some-dummy-url/ping"
    totalHits, _ := strconv.Atoi("50000")
    waitGroup.Add(totalHits)

    for i := 0; i < totalHits; i++ {
        go MakeRequests(url, ch, &waitGroup)
    }

    for i := 0; i < totalHits; i++ {
        if <-ch == 200 {
            count++
        }
    }
    waitGroup.Wait()

    fmt.Printf("Total number of successfull request :" + strconv.Itoa(count))
}
```

Error

```
Get http://some-dummy-url/ping: dial tcp 10.120.0.45:80: connect: can't assign requested address
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x123da32]

goroutine 13425 [running]:
main.MakeRequests(0x7ffeefbff868, 0x22, 0xc0000880c0, 0xc0000ae290)
        /Users/kshitij/go/src/github.com/pingService/healthCheck.go:19 +0xe2
created by main.main
        /Users/kshitij/go/src/github.com/pingService/healthCheck.go:33 +0x136
exit status 2
```

Comment: Do you actually get various errors, or you just get the one error you pasted?

Comment: And what is on line 19 of healtCheck.go?

Comment: @Filmzy I am getting this errror after fixing couple of them. And on line 19 i am just accessing response code from response of api request

Comment: Well something on line 19 is trying to dereference a nil pointer. Since you've only described it, and not shown the actual code in question, I can't be more specific.

Comment: The code you posted does not lead to that stack trace.

Comment: line 19 is : ch <- resp.StatusCode

Comment: You're not handling errors properly. In case of an error, you print it, but then proceed as if no error occurred, which leads to your panic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must close `resp.Body` in `MakeRequests`.

The other problem causing the error is that you try to access  `StatusCode` when `resp` is nil due to an error.

Here is the code fixed.

```golang
func MakeRequests(url string, ch chan<- int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(10)) * time.Millisecond)
    resp, err := http.Get(url)
    if resp != nil {
        ch <- resp.StatusCode
        defer func() {
            _, err = io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, resp.Body)
            resp.Body.Close()
        }()
    } else {
        ch <- -1 // because main expect exactly totalHit values in ch
    }
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Comment: @KshiTijSiNgh I updated my answer to provide you with an explanation of the error and the corrected code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following library:

**Requests**: *A Go library for reduce the headache when making HTTP requests (20k/s req)*

https://github.com/alessiosavi/Requests

The idea is to allocate a list of request, than send them with a configurable "parallel" factor that allow to run only "N" request at time.

```golang
// This array will contains the list of request
var reqs []requests.Request

// N is the number of request to run in parallel, in order to avoid "TO MANY OPEN FILES. N have to be lower than ulimit threshold"
var N int = 12

// Create the list of request
for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
    // In this case, we init 1000 request with same URL,METHOD,BODY,HEADERS 
    req, err := requests.InitRequest("https://127.0.0.1:5000", "GET", nil, nil, true) 
    if err != nil {
        // Request is not compliant, and will not be add to the list
        log.Println("Skipping request [", i, "]. Error: ", err)
    } else {
        // If no error occurs, we can append the request created to the list of request that we need to send
        reqs = append(reqs, *req)
    }
}
```

At this point, we have a list that contains the requests that have to be sent.
Let's send them in parallel!

```golang
// This array will contains the response from the givens request
var response []datastructure.Response

// send the request using N request to send in parallel
response = requests.ParallelRequest(reqs, N)

// Print the response
for i := range response {
    // Dump is a method that print every information related to the response
    log.Println("Request [", i, "] -> ", response[i].Dump())
    // Or use the data present in the response
    log.Println("Headers: ", response[i].Headers)
    log.Println("Status code: ", response[i].StatusCode)
    log.Println("Time elapsed: ", response[i].Time)
    log.Println("Error: ", response[i].Error)
    log.Println("Body: ", string(response[i].Body))
}
```

You can find example usage into the example folder of the repository.

***SPOILER***:

> *I'm the author of this little library*